# Run functions inside for loop

Tags: java, function, random

I want to run my function many times and get different answers(because it deals with random numbers), and get the minimum from all possible answers. But the function always returns the same value. How can I correct the loop to get different answers each time and find their minimum? 
Here is my code

```
    int n = 0;
    KargerMinimumCut karger = new KargerMinimumCut();
    ArrayList<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        n = karger.minCut(vertices);
        answers.add(n);
    }
    int min = minimum(answers);
    System.out.println("Minimum Number is: " + min);
```

and the minimum function

```
public static int minimum(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
    int min = array.get(0);
    for(int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if(array.get(i) < min)
            min = array.get(i);
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: Where's the randomness?

Comment: The rnadomness is inside the minCut function. It returns different answers when I run it, but inside the loop it returns allways the same answer

Comment: Care to show us the minCut method?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to show the implementation of the "minCut" method - as it stands "minimum" method looks fine, so presumably the problem is somewhere else

Comment: minCut function is very long and sophisticated, so I will not post it here, but the problem is that it returns different values when I run it outside the loop, but inside the loop it always returns the same value

Comment: Then just show us your random number generator.

Comment: Yep, you are using an ArrayList of ArrayLists for your set of vertices. You do permanent damage to it the first time you run your algorithm. Keep a copy of it and re-initialize it on every run. That way you get different answers every time.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Okay after seeing your algorithm you need to do this. (I would have just used a simple 2D array of Integers by the way).

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
KargerMinimumCut karger = new KargerMinimumCut();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int cut = karger.minCut(copyOfVertices(vertices));
    System.err.println(cut);
    min = Math.min(min,cut);
}
System.out.println("Minimum Number is: " + min);
```

.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> copyOfVertices(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> vertices) {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> copy = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
  int size = vertices.size();
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    int innerSize = vertices.get(i).size();
    ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j=0; j<innerSize; j++) {
      row.add(new Integer(vertices.get(i).get(j)));
    }
    copy.add(row);
  }
  return copy;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I see what values returns minCut during every iteration?

Comment: I edited my answer, you don't actually need to print out the vertices but you can if you needed to.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried this and it printed the same value of cut 10 times :(  The interesting thing is that when I run it outside the loop, every time I run I get different answers

Comment: Show us your minCut method, we already told you in the OP.

Comment: Edited again, try this.